# Array of objects from array containing objects with values contained in another array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Is there possibility to get an array of objects without loops like:

Imagine that with have arrays:
A : [1,2,3,4]

B -< array of dictionaries

B : [["code",a,"id",4],["code", b, "id", 2],["code", c","id",4"],["code", d,"id",5"]];

and now I want to get an array that the ids from B are in A so the result array would look like:
C: [["code",a,"id",4],["code", b, "id", 2],["code", c","id",4"]]

How to do this without loops? Maybe some predicates or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, predicates would do the trick here:

```
[B filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", A]];
```

Note that this only works if you work with NSNumbers rather than straight ints - those cannot be stored in NSArrays or NSDictionaries. (NSStrings would work as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You mention an array of dictionaries but in your example I see an array of arrays. That is a bit confusing.

Anyway I think what you are looking for is a method on NSArray: [filteredArrayUsingPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:)